# Inheritance behavior issue

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I m create a class and i m inherit class

```
public class abc : Manager, Inteface
{
    public abc() { string a = context; } 
}
```

When i m inherit class first and interface only then i m able to get context of Manager class.

when i inherit interface first then manager class ,then i m not able to access context of manager class.

```
 public class abc : Inteface,Manager
{
    public abc() { string a = context; } // I m not able to access the context of Manager class. 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply invalid C#, and the compiler should be telling you about it - the class that you're deriving from should appear first in the list.

As an example of the compiler error message you should be getting:

```
public interface IFoo {}
public class Base {}
public class Derived : IFoo, Base {}
```

Output:

> Test.cs(5,30): error CS1722: Base class 'Base' must come before any interfaces

From the C# 5 specification, section 10.1.4:

> A class declaration may include a class-base specification, which defines the direct base class of the class and the interfaces (§13) directly implemented by the class.
>
> *class-base*:
>    `:` *class-type*
>    `:` *interface-type-list*
>    `:` *class-type*  `,` *interface-type-list*
>
> *interface-type-list*:
>    `:` *interface-type*
>    `:` *interface-type-list* `,` *interface-type*

Comment: thanks for reply, but i m not found any documentation regarding this, so can you give the reference link.

Comment: @AnkitRana: What bet? (I've now cited the specification.)

Comment: For an easier read, this is also documented on the msdn under [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx): "When a base type list contains a base class and interfaces, the base class must come first in the list."

Answer (score 0):

C# provides single inheritance, so you can inherit only one class and syntactically C# consider first class to be inherited after ":" colon.

anything second will be treated as interface.